# how to use set layer value automatically when use explicit animation?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I can animately move a layer like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.layer.position]];
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)]];
[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
self.layer.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
```

however, I have to set the layer.position after the end of animation, is there a way to set it automatically when using explicit animation?

Comment: Why do you have to change the value at the end of the animation and to which value?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple documentation, you have to set it manually :

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW3

```
CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeAnim.duration = 1.0;
[theLayer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];

// Change the actual data value in the layer to the final value.
theLayer.opacity = 0.0;
```

> Unlike an implicit animation, which updates the layer object’s data value, an explicit animation does not modify the data in the layer tree. Explicit animations only produce the animations. At the end of the animation, Core Animation removes the animation object from the layer and redraws the layer using its current data values. If you want the changes from an explicit animation to be permanent, you must also update the layer’s property as shown in the preceding example.